# What are the symmetries of circular billiards that makes it integrable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory, integrable-systems

I have often heard that integrability in is equivalent to extensively many conserved quantities $A_i$, i.e. the Poisson bracket $\{H,A_i\}=0$ or in quantum mechanics $[H,A_i]=0$.

- What are the conserved quantities $A_i$ for classical circular billiard, which is integrable?
- What are the conserved quantities in the quantum circular billiard?

My guess is that since momentum $P$ and angular momentum $J_3$ commute with $H$, we could just say that the $A_i$ are the set of all functions $f(P,J_3)$, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

2D circular [billiard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards) is [Liouville integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability):

1. The Hamiltonian $H$ itself is always an [integral of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion) for an [autonomous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)).
2. The boundary force is a [central force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force), so the angular position variable $\theta$ is cyclic, and hence the angular momentum $J_3$ is an integral of motion.

Linear 2-momentum $\vec{p}$ is not an integral of motion at the boundary; its square $\vec{p}^2$ (or any function thereof) is an integral of motion, but not independent of the Hamiltonian $H$.

(Interestingly, [elliptic billiard](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=elliptic+billiard+integrable) is also Liouville integrable.)

Comment: Thank you. What is the criterion for integrability in the quantum setting? Is it simply that there exists one independent operator commuting with $H$, in this case $J_3$?